# onDestroy got executed right away without using onMount

Tags: vite, sveltekit

I got this very weird error that the home page of my Sveltekit app is not mounted, instead, it got destroyed right away. The other routes work just fine but only the "/" route

Comment: Show code/files structure and what exactly you do. These callbacks get executed at various points, potentially also during build and SSR.